# Invoke generic method at runtime with reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to create a convention style class for Entity Framework Core 3 and a little stumped on a generics scenario. I'm not using `DbSet<TEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }`, rather I've created a core EntityDbContext which provides CQRS interfaces and access to the DbSets is done with `dbContext.Set<TEntity>()`. This means I have a reusable DbContext across all projects I use this framework with which is great, but it does mean I have to think differently from time to time.

So I have a requirement to provide Temporal Table support and I annotate my entity classes with an empty interface called IHistoryEnabled. In My DbModelCreator class I scan loaded assemblies for classes implementing IEfDbConvention and then call SetConvention(...). In the HistoryEnabledTableConvention I just need to check if the entity implements IHistoryEnabled and then call:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>(b => b.UseTemporalTable());
```

That is provided by the library [EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables](https://github.com/findulov/EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables).
Because this convention has no idea aboout the type I can't specify it directly as a generic type. Does anyone know how I can actually invoke the Entity method shown but using a type determined at runtime?
As an example I have an entity class `Employment : IHistoryEnabled` and the ClrType at runtime is Employment
[image]

Here's the code as text for convenience:

```
public class HistoryEnabledTableConvention : IEfDbConvention
{
    public void SetConvention(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entityType.ClrType.GetInterfaces().ToList().Any(t => t.Name == nameof(IHistoryEnabled)))
            {
                // Need to replace this line...
                modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>(b => b.UseTemporalTable());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The full solution with a working example is [here](https://github.com/steveski/Perigee.Framework/tree/features/DatabaseRecordHistory). To get it running just test the ExampleConsoleApp as the start project.

Comment: use `Entity(Type)`  ( prolly like `Entity(entityType.ClrType, ...)` ) instead `Entity<TEntity>(...)`

Comment: As a side note, I think: `entityType.ClrType.GetInterfaces().ToList().Any(t => t.Name == nameof(IHistoryEnabled))` could be replaced with `typeof(IHistoryEnabled).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType)`

Comment: Is IsAssignableFrom a better option?

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting Type argument for method cannot be inferred from usage.

Comment: [ModelBuilder.Entity()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_Entity_System_Type_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder__) ... so you can use it like `modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType, b => b.UseTemporalTable())` ... edit: ok it's problem with library ... you need to compile from source and add `UseTemporalTable` with second parameter `IEntityType`

Comment: or rather [in file](https://github.com/findulov/EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables/blob/master/EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables/Extensions/EntityTypeBuilderExtensions.cs) add method  `public static void UseTemporalTable(this EntityTypeBuilder entity)
        {
            TemporalEntitiesCache.Add(entity.Metadata);
        }` and similar remove

Comment: [I filled an issue](https://github.com/findulov/EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables/issues/21) maybe they will fix it some day :)

Comment: @Selvin Awesome, thanks for that. So is it conventional to provide that as a standard?

Comment: hehe for now it seems like you have to get access to  `TemporalEntitiesCache` via reflection (as it's internal class)  and your add your  `entityType` instead using `UseTemporalTable` ... or fork, make changes which i wrote and then using your own version of this llibrary